# What's the best exercise to master 2-5-1 or cycle of 5ths on a chromatic accordion (B-system)

Tags: jazz, accordion

When I started learning jazz on the piano, I was shown a very good exercice to learn voicings in all scales. It started Am7-D7-G7M-C7M-F#dim-B7-Em7-Bb, then it went on the same from Bbm7-Eb7-... It was pretty hard to get it all right, but in the end it got to teach you good voicings for every single 2-5-1.

Is there something similar for the chromatic accordion? (ideally with fingering for B-system)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for--are you talking about the Omnibus Progression or something similar to that scale? [see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnibus_progression ] As for exercise, are you talking about improvising, sight-reading, or playing the Chromatic Accordi?

Comment: Let's say I am comping on Autumn Leaves on the piano. I am not going to play the basic form of each chord, i.e. Am7=A-C-E-G then D7=D-F#-A-C , instead I am going to play some chords in an inverted fashion, and always trying to avoid moving any fingers that are common to 2 chords that follow each other. So for instance here A and C are common to the 2 first chord so I will try to leave my fingers on the notes and only move the other fingers. This makes the chord accompaniment much more smooth than if I was playing each chord in its non inverted way.

Comment: You mean on the right hand, I assume. The way I was taught was to start with just using the bottom three rows and then there are three patterns. One starting on the first row for key of C, Eb, F#, A second row for C#, E, G, Bb third row for D, F, G#, B.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, take a standard piano exercise and go through all keys following the cycle of 5ths. Some keys would be more difficult that others, just work on them more. Then you may want to exercise: 1) Chords, 2) Arpeggios, 3) Phrases. You can find plenty of exercises on the Internet, e.g. https://www.scoreexchange.com/scores/124828.html.
Piano voicings work perfectly on accordion. Then you could further explore and use drops and play wider intervals, something that cannot be physically achieved on a piano keyboard. Find what chords sound great to YOU and work on them.

Comment: I addition to my post above, a quick way to learn a particular grip is to take a voicing and go through all keys chromatically up and down with a metronome, starting from a tempo at which you are able to do it without stopping and then increasing the tempo little by little. 
The same metronome trick is actually quite useful when you play a 2-5-1 exercise! Start very slow, where it is comfortable for you (without feeling guilty or ashamed) and there little by little get more comfort and increase the tempo.

Answer (score 0):

what I did on guitar was to learn three different voicings of each chord (min7, maj7, dom7) and then do 2-5-1 then after it make the 1 a min7 ex . Dmin7 -> G7 -> C maj7 -> Cmin7 -> F7 -> Bb maj7 ... etc, I mean you can just do this pattern and write as long as a progression as you need, while also using any chord voicings you know

Answer (score 0):

Spell the chords in your head so that the notes in each chord are second nature
Work out the fingerings 
Simply practice moving through each one of the progressions.
Learn tunes and analyze the changes and make note of the corresponding numbers 
Play each tune in different keys;